# CollapsingToolbarLayout font not changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-fonts

I have a **CollapsingToolbarLayout** like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        app:contentScrim="@color/orange"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_profile_prime"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I tried to change **CollapsingToolbarLayout**'s title, but it didn't changed.

What should I do to change it's font?

Comment: Please add app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
Specifically the last part

.Title

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: Typeface font = Typer.set(yourContext).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_MEDIUM);
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(font);
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(font);

Comment: I want to use a font except Roboto fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your font in directory src/main/assets/fonts and use these code:

```
final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(tf);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use it , its worked for me and changed font in CollapsingToolbarLayout's
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: How to use this library to change **CollapsingToolbarLayout**'s font?

Comment: add to your depency in build.gradle compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

Comment: No. I mean How to set font?

Comment: Add Fonts
Add your custom fonts to assets/. All font definitions are relative to this path.

Assuming that you are using Gradle you should create the assets directory under src/main/ in your project directory if it does not already exist. As it's popular to use multi-project build with Gradle the path is usually app/src/main/assets/, where app is the project name.

You might consider creating a fonts/ subdirectory in the assets directory (as in examples).

Usage
<TextView fontPath="fonts/MyFont.ttf"/>

Comment: Installation
Define your default font using CalligraphyConfig, in your Application class in the #onCreate() method.

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}

Comment: after this work go to wrap this activty to other activty :
Installation
Define your default font using CalligraphyConfig, in your Application class in the #onCreate() method.

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}

Comment: I did these but my font not changed.

Comment: @behrooz.fard dash mage nemikhahi font on colaps ro change koni?

Comment: So what should I do?